# Is it possible to build a "sub jar" of a Maven project?

Tags: maven, jar, maven-assembly-plugin, maven-jar-plugin

I have a situation at the moment where I have:

Project A which is built into a fat `jar` using Maven assembly plugin.

Project B which uses the `jar` built in Project A. It is added to the project as a resource and launched in a separate process using a process builder.

I wonder if it's possible to achieve similar behaviour using just one Maven project. I.e build the `jar` containing only the classes and dependencies required for project A, and then build the rest of the project with the prebuilt `jar`.

Sorry if I'm not being very clear here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is against a few of Maven's core concepts:

- One project, one model (POM). Two projects (A, B), two models (POMs).
- There's one `artifactId` in a POM. What is a second artifact (`jar`) supposed to be named?
- One project leads to one artifact. There is no additional "*prebuilt `jar`*" built within the very same project.
- Dependencies are for the whole project (and possible sub-module projects). I'm not aware of how to "*containing only the classes and dependencies required for project A*".
- Artifacts are stored:

  - in `<project>/target` temporarily
  - in the local Maven repository (default: `~/.m2/repository`)
  - possibly in a remote Maven repository

  ... while resources are taken from `<project>/src/main/resources` during the build.

There might be some tricky solutions (which have possibly pitfalls, too) to achieve this if one thinks about it thoroughly. But I'd never ever recommend such.